# How create new array from looping value date from object?

Tags: javascript

i have object with array of names koktelData.strIngredient1 to 15 and values. I want loop that array and create new array with all values from koktelData.strIngredient1 to 15. I tray something like this but new array have 15 elements undefined1 to undefined15.

```
     var sastojak = koktelData.strIngredient;
  let sastojci = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
    var sastojak_niz = koktelData.strIngredient + [i];
    const sastajak = sastojci.push(sastojak_niz);
  }
  console.log(sastojci);
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to [edit] your questions.

Answer (score 2):

try this out

```
 let sastojci = [];

 for (let i = 1, j = 0; i < 16; i++, j++) {
        sastojci[j] = koktelData.strIngredient + i
 
 }

 console.log(sastojci);
```

If coktelData.strIngredient is an array then it should start at 0.

And this is how it should work. If not then contact me and add koktelData.strIngredient to the question so I can test it.

If koktelData.strIngredient is an String then pls show format

Comment: what langues is it and what data type is koktelData.strIngredient?

Comment: [link] (https://ibb.co/0CW3v4N) here is what look exact...i try your example and get same results

Comment: pls say language and what datatype is it

Comment: it is javasctipt and i try get data from object json...have array with 15 elements strIngredient1 to strIngredient15. i want loop that and get value

Comment: try this out but without the json object is difficult, so you should have not only the content but also the variable

Comment: only what is problem when I try change last number of name from data... iI try koktelData.strIngredient + [i] and get array of underfind if i hardcore number i get value

Comment: did you try my code. it worked for me but mane also gets the variable name

Comment: i try what u suggest but don't work. koktelData.strIngredient isn't string its data from object...

Comment: i know but how get you that

Comment: sry but with so little information it is difficult to give a solution. i often asked you for info but you always ignored it. Sorry that I could not help but have no desire and no motivation more

Comment: i fatch url and get json object with all data now want manipulate with same

Comment: i know but without the structure it is difficult sry in java is it easy

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to loop through an object's properties (`koktelData.strIngredient1` to `koktelData.strIngredient15`) and create an array containing their values. You can achieve this using a `for` loop and dynamic property access. Here's the corrected code:

```js
var sastojci = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
  var sastojak_niz = koktelData["strIngredient" + i];
  sastojci.push(sastojak_niz);
}
console.log(sastojci);
```

In this code:

1. We initialize an empty array `sastojci` to store the values.
2. We use a `for` loop to iterate from 1 to 15.
3. Inside the loop, we dynamically access the object properties using bracket notation like `koktelData["strIngredient" + i]`. This allows us to access `koktelData.strIngredient1` through `koktelData.strIngredient15`.
4. We push each value into the `sastojci` array.
5. Finally, we log the `sastojci` array to the console, which should contain all the values from `koktelData.strIngredient1` to `koktelData.strIngredient15`.